# Valgrind: Invalid write of size 1 on a strcpy

Tags: c, valgrind

The code is attempting to serialize a large uint8_t array into a binary character stream. I should have plenty of room in the buffer to copy this data; why am I getting these errors? Posted is a complete runnable code with the output error. The valgrind command used is:

`valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./prog`

**Main:**

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 9236
#define DAT_LEN 8202

void create_bit_stream(uint8_t frame[], size_t frame_size, char *frame_bits)
{
  /*
   * Takes in uint8_t array of data and converts to binary stream of characters
   * frame        : input array of uint8_t type data
   * frame_size   : size_t length of frame --> sizeof(frame)/sizeof(frame[0])
   * frame_bits   : pointer for returning the character string
   *
   * RETURNS string of binary values generated from input array
  */

  uint8_t tmp[frame_size];
  memset(tmp,0,frame_size);
  memcpy(tmp,frame,frame_size);
  // char bit_string[frame_size*8+1];
  char *bit_string = malloc(frame_size*8+1);
  memset(bit_string,'\0',frame_size*8 + 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < frame_size; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      bit_string[i*8+j] = '0' + (tmp[i] >> 7);
      tmp[i] <<= 1;
    }
  }
  bit_string[frame_size*8] = '\0';
  strcpy(frame_bits, bit_string);
  free(bit_string);
  return;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 char *frame_bits = malloc(MAX_FRAME_SIZE + 1);
 if(!frame_bits)
 {exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
 memset(frame_bits,'\0',MAX_FRAME_SIZE + 1);

 uint8_t *DAT_frame = malloc(DAT_LEN);
 if(!DAT_frame)
 {exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
 memset(DAT_frame,0,DAT_LEN);

 //fill with arbitrary data
 for(int i = 0; i < DAT_LEN; i++)
 {
   DAT_frame[i] = i % 255;
 }

 create_bit_stream(DAT_frame, DAT_LEN, frame_bits);

 free(frame_bits); free(DAT_frame);
 return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
==2994== Invalid write of size 1
==2994==    at 0x4C31060: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2994==    by 0x40088B: create_bit_stream (stack.c:36)
==2994==    by 0x400993: main (stack.c:61)
==2994==  Address 0x5205455 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9,237 alloc'd
==2994==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2994==    by 0x4008CE: main (stack.c:45)
==2994== 
==2994== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x5203040, 0x52074f0)
==2994==    at 0x4C310E6: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2994==    by 0x40088B: create_bit_stream (stack.c:36)
==2994==    by 0x400993: main (stack.c:61)
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but FYI, `sizeof(char)` is 1 **by definition**, thus `foo * sizeof(char)` is redundant and a bad code smell.

Comment: you're gonna have to cut this down there's too much noise in the question

Comment: @RyanHaining not sure what you would have me remove. There are two pointer initializations and a very small function. There is literally nothing extraneous here.

Comment: Further explanation: you might not think `sizeof(uint8_t)` was the same thing as `sizeof(char)`, but it has to be, because `char` cannot be _smaller_ than `uint8_t` (`CHAR_BIT >= 8` is required), and if it is _bigger_ (i.e. `CHAR_BIT > 8`), then the implementation is required to _not provide `uint8_t`_.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (after putting back in the `#include`s and the top-level file structure -- please don't make people do that in the future, provide a [minimal but *complete* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and am investigating.

Comment: Thank you @zwol for the advice; I will post accordingly in the future. Are you saying that I should not be using `sizeof(uint8_t)` as well; I'm not sure I understood your point there.

Comment: *Are you saying that I should not be using `sizeof(uint8_t)`* -- Yes. The standard guarantees that either `sizeof(uint8_t) == 1` or `uint8_t` does not exist, and the odds of encountering an implementation where `uint8_t` does not exist are vanishingly small (unless you take a notion to port your code to the [PDP-10](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/)).

Comment: Re "*I will post accordingly in the future*", It's not too late. Please provide a runnable demonstration

Comment: @ikegami updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create_bit_stream` takes a stream of bytes and expands it to a stream of **ASCII-coded** bits.  That is, if you feed it byte 0x42 ('B') it will produce the *string* "`01000010`", which is nine bytes long (counting the terminating nul).  You forgot to take this into account when you allocated space for `frame_bits` -- not in `create_bit_stream`, but in `main`:

```
char *frame_bits = (char *)malloc((MAX_FRAME_SIZE + 1)*sizeof(char));
```

should read

```
char *frame_bits = malloc(MAX_FRAME_SIZE * 8 + 1);
```

([Don't cast the result of `malloc`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

(As I pointed out in the comments on the question, `sizeof(char) == 1` and `sizeof(uint8_t) == 1` *by definition*; explicitly writing either is redundant and a bad code smell.)

(APIs like these, where the caller supplies a variable-length buffer that the callee writes into, should always pass in the size of the output buffer.  Your design is dangerous for the same reason that `gets` and `sprintf` are dangerous.)

Comment: using this correction valgrind still complains of `Invalid write of size 1` in the `strcpy` function. edit: I am using `valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./program`

Comment: @gutelfuldead After making the above change I get no further complaints from `valgrind`. The remaining problem is probably in the part of your code that I had to reconstruct.  Please edit your question and supply the _complete_ source code to your test program.

Comment: you are correct. I'm not sure where the issue was coming from; I refactored it into a single source and it worked. Thanks.